# NSKeyedArchive crash the app, alternative method?

Tags: ios, swift, nskeyedarchiver

Here’s the question: I need to save in local a dictionary of type [String:[MyCustomObject] ], but since my array of custom objects (MyCustomObject is a class which can contain a String or an UIImage) can reach dimensions like 200-300 MB, with NSKeyArchive root object my app crash or, if the size is lower, it takes up to 5 seconds to close the app definitely. Any suggestions for how can achieve this saving without crash or taking too much time?

Comment: Save the image data (jpeg representation) locally and just save its name and directory in your plist file

Comment: @LeoDabus how to save them locally? Which method may I have to use?

Comment: The images are fetched via backend, I don’t have them within my project

Comment: Just use UIImageJPEGRepresentation to convert your image to data and use Data write method to write it to disk